Module Parse Failed when using pdfjs-dist with Electron + Vue
When I import pdfjs-dist in my Electron Vue project, I get the following error:

error  in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1413:9) You may need an
appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
configured to process this file. See
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | | class
PDFDocumentLoadingTask {

static #docId = 0; | |   constructor() {


Similar questions have suggested modifying webpack. I'm working off a clone of this project, which doesn't have a webpack config, but does have a very simple babel.config.js.
The offending line is
import * as pdf from 'pdfjs-dist';

The offending line is actually static #docId = 0; not the import :p clearly

True! My electron app doesn't know how to handle the # styling of private variables.
